# Not running with JRE 8

Tags: java, deprecated

I have this huge legacy code that is built upon Java and C that uses JNI calls etc. It is working fine with JRE 7. I am getting following exception while running on JRE 8.

```
#INVENTORYTUNER: Finished setting trusted transmitters, added: vw-pun-mar-dv07
#java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/CharToByteConverter
#   at com.marimba.tools.util.ByteBuffer.setEncoding(ByteBuffer.java:109)
#   at com.marimba.tools.util.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:97)
#   at com.marimba.tools.logs.LogEntry.<init>(LogEntry.java:21)
#   at com.marimba.tools.logs.GenericLog.logData(GenericLog.java:91)
#   at com.marimba.tools.logs.GenericLog.log(GenericLog.java:84)
#   at com.marimba.tools.logs.LogDispatcher.log(LogDispatcher.java:267)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Workspace.log(Workspace.java:1112)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Workspace.log(Workspace.java:1031)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Workspace.log(Workspace.java:1024)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:180)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Workspace.getChannelCreate(Workspace.java:701)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.tuner.Workspace.getChannelCreate(Workspace.java:684)
#   at com.marimba.castanet.launch.Launcher$Create.run(Launcher.java:399)
#   at com.marimba.tools.util.ThreadPool.runClient(ThreadPool.java:374)
#   at com.marimba.tools.util.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:360)
#   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Internally, we are using this zip to support deprecated methods. How to proceed this ?

Comment: what is `com.marimba`? A public library? An internal library to you company?

Comment: `sun.*` normally are _internal_ packages you should _not_ use since they can be removed (and probably were in that case) in any release of the JDK. Thus you either have to run that application with Java 7  or refactor it.

Comment: actually the sun.io.CharToByteConverter is a deprecated class since 1.7

Comment: @Thomas probably. https://java.net/projects/java-nio-charset-enhanced/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/sun/io/CharToByteConverter.java?rev=1123 you can read more. In particular, `@deprecated Replaced by {@link java.nio.charset}. THIS API WILL BE REMOVED IN J2SE 1.6.`

Comment: yes, com.marimba is an internal library, I am trying to find a way to resolve this deprecation using adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is marbima something you are using as a third party lib or something that you are working on?

As folks in the comments mentioned the `CharToByteConverter` has been replaced by `java.nio.charset`

See [Java Class chartobyteconverter Type deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444129/java-class-chartobyteconverter-type-deprecated)

If you are using marbima as a third party lib, contact the devs to see if it is certified for JDK 1.8, if you develop it, you need to modify it to remove the deprecated classes.