# Is there any Java 8 supported release of SqlJ?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, sqlj

Actually I am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:sun/io/CharToByteConverter
```

This is because in Java 8, the CharToByteConverter class has been removed as it was deprecated.

Now I want to know of any alternative which would replace this package/class and provide its functionality without throwing the exception mentioned above.

This class is used in the SQLJ's

```
Translator.jar
```

and inside it it is in

```
sqlj.util.io.OracleOutputStream.class
```

Edit:
If I replace the CharToByteConverter class with the java.nio.charset class, still the SQLJ might not be able to detect it. Please correct me if I am wrong. And let me know if replacing the CharToByteConverter with java.nio.charset might fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444129/java-class-chartobyteconverter-type-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but WAS an issue for me until today as well. So maybe others may benefit from the information, that Oracle has a bug #21315718 for that, containing the solution:
"Translator.jar and runtime12.jar were not compatible with JDK 8.
The issue is reported in unpublished Bug 21315718 - sqlj translator does not work with jdk 8."
After upgrading these two jars, SQLJ did not raise the above error for me.

Answer (score -2):

The javadoc comment says it all:

> Deprecated! Replaced - by java.nio.charset

Look for a replacement
 class/method in the java.nio.charset package.

Note that using classes in the JDK that are not part of the officially documented API is a bad idea in the first place

Comment: Instead of copy pasting an answer you should have marked it as duplicate  :)

Comment: I have already read this post which suggests what you have mentioned above. However, java.nio.charset is a replacement for the deprecated class CharToByteConverter.class
However, I am looking for a replacement for the entire Translator.jar file.
The reason being that even if I replace the CharToByteConverter class with charset, it will still cause errors while I use the translator.jar which SQLJ internally uses as a library.
I am sorry as I probably wrote my question wrong. Ill edit it to provide a better view of my problem.